# Can't clone GitHub remote repo. MediaTypeNotDetected

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to clone a remote repository within visual studio 2015 using the GitHub extension. However no matter what I do I always get the same error.

```
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (MediaTypeNotDetected).
```

Can anyone shed some light on what this error means as I can't find anything about it through my own research.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I'm guessing you tried to clone on a machine whose web content is being filtered by a firewall. Probably your computer at work.